# Unable to create credentials in the deeveloper console

Tags: google-oauth

I've been trying to create a new application using the Calendar API.  Once I set up the API, create the OAuth consent screen, and try to create a new credential, I just get the spinning wheel on that tab... in the Chrome console, I'm seeing a lot of errors (below).  I've disabled any ad-blockers, tried to do this using a Guest instance of Chrome, tried MS Edge, and IE 11... all of them give the same result.

Console Errors (snippets):
credentials?highlightClient=617400695149-a43k8sak7l9jelev1er07ksvas25ee7p.apps.googleusercontent.com&clientUpdateTime=2019-02-09T14:47:12.511862Z&project=oauth-personal:1 Refused to display 'https://apikeys.clients6.google.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.XJ59ec7s7KY.O%2Fam%3DwQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNs5IgvBOFBg5RBx9jQCiMeE_z9Dg%2Fm%3D__features__#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com&rpctoken=503889176' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/CONSOLE_PINS/keys/CLOUD?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g:1 GET https://cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/CONSOLE_PINS/keys/CLOUD?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g 404
m=core,jsmod_apiui:59 ERROR Yb {url: "https://cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v…CLOUD?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g", headers: Map(6), status: 404, statusText: "OK", method: "GET", …}

cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/CONSOLE_NAV_HIDE_PRODUCTS?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g:1 GET https://cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/CONSOLE_NAV_HIDE_PRODUCTS?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g 404
cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/PAN_NOTIFICATION_BELL_LAST_OPENED?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g:1 GET https://cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/PAN_NOTIFICATION_BELL_LAST_OPENED?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g 404

Comment: same issue here for the maps API. Did you find a workaround? Tried several browsers, private navigation etc. nothing, still stuck on my side.